# How to emulate MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX() in scala?

Tags: mysql, scala

How can I emulate MySQL function SUBSTRING_INDEX() in scala using scala string functions?

For example 
MySQL:

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('This is test number one', ' ', 3);`

returns `This is test`

How to achieve same in scala?

Comment: I am not getting your output can you please explain in more detail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get this either. This is a bit simpler solution that works as desired.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val str = "this is a string"
    val substring = takeWords(str, ' ', 3)
    println(substring) // yields "this is a"
  }

  def takeWords(s: String, splitAt: Char, n: Int): String = {
    s.split(splitAt) take n mkString(" ") //or whatever separator you need
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this one but I think it should work as expected;

```
 def substringWithIndex(str: String, splitter: String, index: Int): String = {
    str.split(splitter).zipWithIndex.foldLeft("") { (acc, i) =>
      if(i._2 == 0)
        i._1
      else if(i._2 < index)
        acc + splitter + i._1
      else
        acc
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def substringIndex(str: String, n: Int, splitter: String = "\\s+"): String = 
    str split splitter take n mkString " "
```